# can I place a input field within a link, without making the input a link too?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have the following problem: I have a Newsletter Banner with some content (Text, Icons and stuff) and the most important: input for E-Mail+submitbutton.

Now I would like to link the whole newsletter banner to a subpage with more information about the newsletter, but when I then click the textfield or submitbutton I get redirected to the link...

Is there any solution for this problem?

Here is a fiddle showing the problem:
try to click the `input` and you see it´ll be a link.

https://jsfiddle.net/wu6js2v7/2/

Btw: its no solution for me to only party link the banner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had another idea, which works fine for this. Or better even 2 possibilities:

the first one is: position absolute the input (won´t work in my case, but maybe helps others)

the second one is ofc Javascript, I´m using a "data-link" attribute in the wrapperdiv and this does the magic:

```
$(".datalink_click").on("click", function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('data-link');
    window.location.href = link;
});
$(".datalink_click input").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> can I place a input field within a link

No.

[The specification says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content Model: 
>   Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

An input field is interactive content.

> without making the input a link too?

Not then either.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I hoped there would be a play around.